# Java - Thread safe program

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Consider the following piece of code:

```
public class Test
    {
        private List<Object> list;

        public Object get(int id)
        {
            return list.get(id);
        }

        public void add(Object el)
        {
            list.add(el);
        }

        public List<Object> getList()
        {
            return list;
        }
    }
```

I have to make sure that it is thread safe (there will be no synchronization errors). I am pretty new to this thing, so my guesses are:

1. We add `synchronized` to the `add()` and `get()` methods and we add `synchronized(Test.class)` to the `getList()` method;
2. We make `list` static and all the methods static, then we add `synchronized`;

This is what I came up with, it's possible that neither of them are right though.

Comment: You should read more about thread safe, there is books almost entirely dedicated to that matter. But you share the instance `list` since you have a getter. It would be more complicated to manage it since I could get the instance and add new items in it from anywhere.

Comment: Static has nothing to do with it. You're right about adding synchronized to `get` and `add` but that will not be sufficient as you are exposing the list via `getList`. Return a copy of the list, or make it read-only via `Collections.unmodifiableList`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

synchronize `add`, `get` and `getList`, additionally in `getList` return `UnmodifiableList`:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    private List<Object> list = new LinkedList<>();

    public synchronized Object get(int id) {
        return list.get(id);
    }

    public synchronized void add(Object el) {
        list.add(el);
    }

    public synchronized List<Object> getList() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
    }
}
```

You need to also synchronize the `getList`, because `Collections.unmodifiableList` uses `Iterator` of the supplied list internally to copy it, so it could give `ConcurrentModificationException` if not `synchronized` with the `add` method.

Answer (score 3):

Your point #1 seems valid. I would put `synchronized` on `get()` and `add()` and `getList()`, but I would not put anything static, rather return a copy of the list when `getList()` is called.

Since you do not specify which type, I wrote the snippet with `ArrayList` as example.

```
  public synchronized List<Object> getList()
  {
      return new ArrayList<Object>(list);
  }
```

If you want to emphasise good practices, you could return some sort of immutable collection in order to prevent the "user" of this class from editing the list, believing it may affect the state.

```
public synchronized List<Object> getList()
{
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
}
```

Comment: If you leave the getList unsynchronized it can throw ConcurrentModificationException  if other thread will call add in the same time

Comment: No, it stops all threads other than the one already in synchronized block, to enter any block synchronized on same Object - in this egzample on the Test instance.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting @hugo, its one of my first answers. :)

Answer (score 2):

Using a static modifier means sharing the same `list` field for all instances of the Test class.
Consequently, your class should be a singleton and it seems not designed to be it.
So, using static doesn't seem necessarily the best way to address your need.

To make your class thread safe, you have to limit the possibility that its state may change concurrently by multiple threads.

So this should be changed :

```
    public List<Object> getList()
```

Otherwise the clients may modify concurrently the List instance that is returned.

You should return a unmodifiable list.

You should also synchronize the methods for adding and removing elements to avoid concurrent add or removal operation.

In this way the class is synchronized :

```
public class Test
    {
        private List<Object> list;

        public synchronized Object get(int id)
        {
            return list.get(id);
        }

        public synchronized void add(Object el)
        {
            list.add(el);
        }

        public synchronized List<Object> getList() {
           return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
        }

    }
```

Now if you chain call to these methods, you should also synchronize them since between their call, another thread could change the state of the list.

For example this code :

```
Test test = ...;
int index = ...;
Object myObject = ...;

if (test.get(index) != myObject){
    test.add(myObject);
}
```

should be written in this way :

```
Test test = ...;
int index = ...;
Object myObject = ...;

synchronized(test){
  if (test.get(index) != myObject){
      test.add(myObject);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you leave the getList unsynchronized it can throw ConcurrentModificationException  if other thread will call add in the same time

Comment: @Krzysztof Cichocki Of course. I have already edited to change it.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of them is completely right.

> We add synchronized to the add() and get() methods and we add synchronized(Test.class) to the getList() method;

Add synchronized to `add()` , `get()` and `getList()`. But adding `synchronized(Test.class`)  to `getList()` is wrong since you are adding class lock instead of object level lock to access object variable.

> We make list static and all the methods static, then we add synchronized;

This is required if you need only one list across all instances of `Test` => class level member variable instead of object level member variable. Otherwise, just proceed with instance method level lock instead of class level lock. Follow first approach.

For class level variables, use class level locks. For object level variables, use object level locks.

Refer to oracle  pages of [Synchronized Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html)  and  [Intrinsic Locks and Synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) for better understanding of concepts.

Few notes from documentation pages:

**Object level lock:**

Making these methods `synchronized` has two effects:

1. First, it is not possible for two invocations of `synchronized` methods on the same object to interleave. When one thread is executing a `synchronized` method for an object, all other threads that invoke `synchronized` methods for the same object block (suspend execution) until the first thread is done with the object.
2. Second, when a `synchronized` method exits, it automatically establishes a happens-before relationship with any subsequent invocation of a `synchronized` method for the same object. This guarantees that changes to the state of the object are visible to all threads

**Class level lock:**

You might wonder what happens when a static `synchronized` method is invoked, since a `static` method is associated with a class, not an object. In this case, the thread acquires the intrinsic lock for the `Class` object associated with the class. *Thus access to class's static fields is controlled by a lock that's distinct from the lock for any instance of the class*.

Answer (score 0):

That piece of code is thread safe already. Why ? because the global variable is non-static variable. All the thread will create it's own variable `List<Object> list;`
Except if you make `List<Object> list;` to be a **static** variable.